# Setting up SVN on Slackware

Tags: unix, svn, installation

What is the most basic set of steps required to set up SVN on a fresh installation of Slackware 12?

Comment: 'set up' what? the client? the server? a repo?  sharing of a repo over WEB-DAV? a web-based repository browser?  Without more details, most of your answer is going to be 'read the svn docs'

Answer (score 2):

Subversion already exists in Slackware 12, so you can just install it at setup time. Or you can install it later using installpkg subversion-1.4.4-i486-1.tgz

To start svn server automatically at boot time i'm wrote this script. Name it rc.svnserve and put into /etc/rc.d/ dir. Then insert call  'rc.svnserve start' in script rc.inet2 or rc.local at your flavour.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Start/stop/restart svn server.

# Start svnserve:
svnserve_start() {
  CMDLINE="/usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /home/svn/repositories "
  echo -n "Starting SVN daemon:  $CMDLINE"
  $CMDLINE --pid-file /var/run/svnserve.pid
  echo
}

# Stop svnserve:
svnserve_stop() {
  echo -n "Stopping SVN daemon..."
  kill `cat /var/run/svnserve.pid`
  echo
  sleep 1
  rm -f /var/run/svnserve.pid
}

# Restart svnserve:
svnserve_restart() {
  svnserve_stop
  sleep 1
  svnserve_start
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  svnserve_start
  ;;
'stop')
  svnserve_stop
  ;;
'restart')
  svnserve_restart
  ;;
*)
  echo "usage $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
```

Comment: Personally I've done it even simpler, I simply added
`/usr/bin/svnserve -d -v /home/svn ` to /etc/rc.d/rc.local, but your version is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Download. (http://subversion.tigris.org/)
2) Follow installation instructions.

There you go, that's just about the most basic set of steps I can think of. =:)

Answer (score 0):

Download svn, and do a ./configure && make install.

Choose a directory to be the root of your subversion server (we'll pretend you chose /var/svn and you're logged in as root) and call 'svnadmin create /var/svn/'.  Create a subversion user and do a 'chown -R subversion /var/svn/'.

Now that you've got your directory ready to roll, start the subversion server with 'sudo -u subversion svnserve -dr /var/svn/'.  To have it start up at boot, add that line to /etc/rc.d/rc.local.